# Why does %scan fail when masked with %str()?

Tags: macros, sas

I'm trying to program a macro that will take in a string of variable names separated by `|` and perform a calculation on them (e.g. `ab dc|def`). I have tried the following code, but I get a strange error on the scan function: "Macro function %SCAN has too few arguments."

`SYMBOLGEN` tells me that `&from.` and `&k.` were resolved correctly: "FROM resolves to ab dc|def" and "K resolves to 1" so I'm not sure what the problem is. Initially I suspected that `%str()` masks the value until after macro execution time, resulting in the parameters not being resolved. But this doesn't seem to be the case, as `%unquote(%str(..scan function..))` gives the same error.

```
%macro data_mapping_sum(from);
  %let k=1;
  %let temp_ind = "%scan(&from., &k.,"|")";
  %let THIS_FAILS = %str(%'%scan(&from., &k.,"|")%'n); 

  %do %while( (&temp_ind. NE "") );
      %unquote(&THIS_FAILS.) = 999; 
      %let k = %eval(&k. + 1);
      %let temp_ind = "%scan(&from., &k.,"|")";
      %let THIS_FAILS = %str(%'%scan(&from., &k.,"|")%'n);
  %end;

%mend;

data test;
%data_mapping_sum(ab dc|def);
run;
```

Comment: P.S. If anyone is interested, I have programmed this in another way that works. Please do let me know if you'd like to see it.

Comment: Feel free to post your solution as an answer. Stack Overflow [encourages answering your own questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Sure, I'll clean up my code before posting here.

Answer (score 0):

Macro functions don't need quotes. This seems to work..as a start

```
%macro data_mapping_sum(from);
 %let k=1;

 %do %while (%scan(&from,&k,|)^=%str());
  %let temp_ind = %scan(&from, &k,|);
  %Put temp_ind(&k)= &temp_ind;
  %let k = %eval(&k. + 1);
 %end;

%mend;

%data_mapping_sum(ab dc|def);
```

Comment: Hi Carolina, thank you for your answer. The reason I needed the quotes was because the strings I'm scanning are names that may have spaces in them. Hence, %str() is needed to mask %' and %'n: %str(%' ..scan function.. %'n) would hopefully resolve to '..name..'n

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave this question open as I don't think that I've fully answered my own question. However, if anyone needs a program with similar functionality, my working code is:

```
%macro data_mapping_sum(from, map_to);

  %let k=1;
  %let temp_ind1 = %scan(&from., &k.,"|");
  %let temp_ind2 = %scan(&map_to., &k.,"|");
  %do %while( ("&temp_ind1." NE "") AND ("&temp_ind2." NE "") AND &k. NE 1000);
      %unquote(%str(%'&temp_ind2.%'n)) = sum(%unquote(%str(%'&temp_ind2.%'n)),%unquote(%str(%'TRAN_&temp_ind1.%'n)));   
      %let k = %eval(&k. + 1);
      %let temp_ind1 = %scan(&from., &k.,"|");
      %let temp_ind2 = %scan(&map_to., &k.,"|");
  %end;
%mend;

data test;
a="%data_mapping_sum(abc d|f,ter|te cy)";
run;
```

I hope that it's helpful.